# Partition system id FDISK

Tags: partition, fdisk

if I change a partition system id to FAT16 with fdisk and make another file system such as ext2 on that partition with mkfs
what is problem? every thing is ok ! so what does (partition system id) do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpreting the partition id is a function of the boot loader.  Linux doesn't really care, it uses other techniques to work out what's in each partition.  However, other operating systems do care (I believe various versions of Windows for example).

Incorrectly labelling the partition may result in other operating systems trying to use it incorrectly.